# SwiftUI: calling function in View body that modifies EnvironmentObject results in infinite loop and app crash

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm designing a macOS app with SwiftUI. I need to modify an `EnvironmentObject` whose value is *calculated* from a `State` variable. To do this, I tried to call a method that does the calculation and updates the `EnvironmentObject`, but the method appears to fall into an infinite loop that causes the app to stop responding.

Can someone explain what's going on? And, how do I achieve the same ends without having this problem?

I wrote this code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
final class Input: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bar = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var foo = 0
    @EnvironmentObject var input: Input

    func increment(code: Int) {

        print("function called")

        switch code {
        case 0:
            input.bar -= 1
        case 1:
            input.bar += 1
        default:
            print("unknown")
        }

        print("\(input.bar)")

    }

    var body: some View {
        increment(code: foo)
        return Text("Hello world!")     // In reality this is code that modifies foo
    }

}
```

When this code is run, the console prints `"function called"` in an infinite loop, and also prints continuously decreasing values of `input.bar`. From my experimentation, I found that:

- Replacing `input.bar` with some other code (e.g. a simple `print` command) does not cause an infinite loop.
- With this same code, setting `foo` to `2` (thus giving the `default` case) also doesn't cause an infinite loop.
- `foo` doesn't need to be a `State` var, the app crashes even if it's a simple variable.

Comment: Again, I don't wanna directly store the `State` var into the `EnvironmentObject`, but the value of the `EnvironmentObject` is based on the `State` var, like in the example code.

Comment: What do you try to achieve by doing this in `body`? You modify value in body which results in refresh by updating body which calls update body ... cycle. Again why in drawing `body`? I'd say it rather design issue.

Comment: @Asperi It's not necessary to be inside `body`, all I need is to be able to update an `EnvironmentObject` every time the `State` variable changes. I'm still in the learning phase, could you please explain how I should implement this? Where else can I call the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to call observable object calculating method in the place where internal state changed, as in following example.

```
final class Input: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bar = 0


    func increment(code: Int) { // it belongs to Input, so should be here

        print("function called")

        switch code {
        case 0:
            bar -= 1
        case 1:
            bar += 1
        default:
            print("unknown")
        }

        print("\(bar)")

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var foo = 0
    @EnvironmentObject var input: Input

    var body: some View {
        Button("Do Something") {
            self.foo = 1          // << changed state
            self.input.increment(code: 1) // << updated calculable
        }
    }

}
```